# Javascript: Trying to access window.variable but it stays undefined even after initialising

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I have initialized 4 global variables in function 1 and have also assigned values to the functions. When I try to access the variables in the next function, only the first variable is accessible. All others are undefined.

Function1 is called when a user fills up basic form information. He is then redirected to an advanced form. After filling up both the forms, the data is then stored in a database.

> Kindly provide some solution.

``````
<!-- language: lang-js -->
`````
    <!--'Postspace.js' File-->
    function function1() {

      window.name = $scope.data.name;
      // window.email = 'c@g.com';
      window.varemail = $scope.data.email;
      window.varmobile = $scope.data.mobile;
      window.varlocation = $scope.data.location;
      console.log(window.name);
      console.log(window.varemail);
      console.log(window.varmobile);
      console.log(window.varlocation);

    }

    function function2() {

      console.log(window.name);
      console.log(window.varemail);
      console.log(window.varmobile);
      console.log(window.varlocation);

      'name': window.name,
        'email': window.varemail,
        'mobile': window.varmobile,
        'location': window.varlocation,
        'working_space': $scope.workingSpace.category,
        'no_of_persons': $scope.noOfPerson,
        'joining_date': $scope.startDate,
        'working_hours': workingHours,
        'period': $scope.period,
        'multipleDays': $scope.multipleDays,

    }
``````

`````
> 
> form.blade.php file
> I am taking the values in the php file in this format: This is an example of 
> how I am accepting the name and the mobile field.               `
````  
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': LoginForm.fullEmail.$invalid && LoginForm.fullEmail.$touched}">

   <p class="form-label ">Your Email</p>
   <div class="row ">
       <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8"> <input type="email" ng-model="data.email" name="fullEmail" class="form-control " required placeholder="EMAIL" ng-model-options="{debounce: 200}"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': LoginForm.fullmobile.$invalid && LoginForm.fullmobile.$touched}">

   <p class="form-label">Your Mobile</p>
   <div class="row">

       <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text"  ng-model="data.mobile" name="fullmobile" class=" form-control" required placeholder="MOBILE" ng-pattern="/^[6-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/"></div>
   </div>
</div>

````
`````

Comment: My guess is values on scope data need to be checked. Because if you try following code it will work as expected - 

function function1() {
  window.name = 'a';
  window.varemail = 'b';
  window.varmobile = 'c';
  window.varlocation = 'd';
}

function function2() {

  console.log(window.name)
  console.log(window.varemail)
 
}

Comment: How are you trying to access the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the code that holds the values for $scope.data object...

Comment: Please check the updated code. I am not able to understand the problem. Since, the global variables are accessible in function1. Why, just the name is defined in function2?